# Openshift with Rails application redirects me to index.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, openshift, spree

I have a Rails application (a Spree store) and successfully deployed it on Openshift. To do so, I copied the contents of the 'config/database.yaml' file in the [Openshift example project](https://github.com/openshift/rails-example) to the corresponding file in my project.

After pushing the project to Openshift, whenever I access the site, I am at the following page. I found out that this page can be found in the 'public' folder where it is called 'index.html'.
[image]

It should be said that i. e. accessing myUrl.rhcloud.com/admin works.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the index.html file from the repo.  Then your default route (root) should work correctly.  Make sure that you updated any other configuration files that are needed for spree also.